# Number of sentences and sentential forms generated by a grammar

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, search-problem, breadth-first-search, program-synthesis

In this question, I'm considering only "finite grammars". A finite grammar can only produce a finite number of distinct sentences. The following grammar is **finite** in my definition:

```
S         → AB
A         → B | a 
B         → a | b
```

It can only generate the following finite number of sentences: `aa`, `ab`, `ba`, `bb`

On the other hand, the following grammar is **not finite**:

```
S         → AB
A         → AA | B | a 
B         → a | b
```

Because it can create an infinite number of sentences: `aa`, `aaa`, `aaaa`, `aaaaa`, ...

Now to the actual question. Suppose the following finite grammar:

```
S         → variable = math_expr
variable  → a | b | c 
math_expr → INT | function
function  → func_1() | func_2(INT, INT, INT, INT)
INT       → 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
```

I want to know if there is some kind of formula that calculate the number of **sentences** and **sentential forms** that can be generated by a finite grammar.

Example of sentences: `b = func_2(2,4,3,3)`, `a = func_1()`

Example of sentential forms: `b = func_2(2,2,INT,INT)`, `c = math_expr`,  `S`

At the moment, I am able to know the number of sentences and sentential forms by applying a Breadth-First Search (BFS) starting from the `S` node.

However, because I'm working with search in program synthesis, it would be great to know the size of the domain without the need of applying an exhaustive search on it.

**Question: How can I find the number of sentences and sentential forms given only an arbitrary finite grammar?**

For the first finite grammar I showed here, the answer is easy to calculate by hand:

Sentences: `aa`, `ab`, `ba`, `bb`
Sentential forms: `S`, `AB`, `BB`, `aB`, `bB`, `Aa`, `Ab`

So the final answer would be 4 + 7 = `11`

However, for the second finite grammar I showed, it is not that easy to calculate it.

**PS.**: In my original problem, I am working with program synthesis with a Domain Specific Language (DSL). I tagged CFG with the hope that the same applies, granted I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: A string which can be derived by a grammar starting with the root symbol is called a [*sentential form*](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/82292/what-is-a-sentential-form). Sentential firms without non-terminals are called *sentences*. In case you were wondering what the usual terminology is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the context-free grammar is [unambiguous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguous_grammar), you can count the number of sentences it generates in a linear scan with a carefully chosen order.

I'll assume we have removed all [useless symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Reachability,_productiveness,_nullability) and cycles from the grammar.  If it is finite and free of useless symbols and cycles, then it should not contain any recursion.

Let $N(A)$ denote the number of sentences that can be constructed starting from nonterminal $A$, i.e., $N(A) = |L(A)|$.  If the grammar is unambiguous and has no recursion, you can compute $N(A)$ for each nonterminal as follows.  Construct a dependency graph with one vertex per nonterminal, and an edge $A \to B$ whenever the grammar contains a rule $B ::= \cdots A \cdots$, i.e., a rule with $B$ on the left-hand side and $A$ on the right-hand side.  If the grammar has no recursion, then this is a dag.  Visit the vertices of this graph in topologically sorted order.  Then it is easy to compute the number of sentences: for example, if we have the rule $A ::= BaC | DE$, then we have

$$N(A) = N(BaC) + N(DE) = N(B) N(a) N(C) + N(D) N(E).$$

That's an example, but you can do the same for any number of alternatives on the right-hand side and any string of symbols in each alternative.  Note that we have the base case $N(a) = 1$, for any terminal $a$.

I expect this can be adjusted to count the number of sentential forms as well, but I haven't tried to work out the details.

This relies crucially on the grammar to be unambiguous.  If the grammar is ambiguous, I'm not sure whether there is any efficient algorithm -- I just don't know.

For unambiguous grammars, see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky%E2%80%93Sch%C3%BCtzenberger_enumeration_theorem, which shows how to count the number of sentences of a particular length, even if the grammar is not finite.

Comment: For sentential forms, you just need to add 1 to every N(A). That's equivalent to adding a new terminal $A'$ for each non-terminal $A$, with the production $A\to 
 A'$